# Styling html progress bar as health bar with value simple Css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a HTML progress bar as a health bar.

I am trying to make it look like this with health value

[image]

I tried this but not working

```css
.progressplayer[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.progressplayer[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<progress class="progressplayer" id="playerhealth" value="100" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment to christians answer:

```
<div class="progress-container">
  <progress id="playerhealth" *ngIf="state==1"   id="playerhealth" value="100" max="100"></progress>
  <p class="progress-label">
    {{playerhp}}
  </p>
  <progress id="enemyhealth" *ngIf="state==1"   id="enemyhealth" value="100" max="100"></progress>
  <p class="progress-label">
    {{mhp}}
  </p>
</div>
```

with this i cant display second progress label.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the `progress` default `appearance`

```
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

See [**CSS-Tricks Article**](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)

```css
.progressplayer[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: green;
}

.progressplayer[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<progress class="progressplayer" id="playerhealth" value="80" max="100"></progress>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `progress` element does not let you natively add text on top of the progress bar, we'll have to use a workaround: positioning a label on top of the progress bar.

As for the styling of the bar, you can style the `progress` element directly and use the pseudo elements to target the `-webkit-progress-bar` and `-webkit-progress-value`:

```css
.progress-container {
    position: relative;
}

.progress-container progress {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 40px;
}

.progress-container progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.progress-container progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: red;
}

.progress-container .progress-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    margin: 0;
    left: 65px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Player health:</h1>
<div class="progress-container player-health">
  <progress class="progressplayer" id="playerhealth" value="80" max="100"></progress>
  <p class="progress-label">
    80%
  </p>
</div>
 
<h1>Enemy health:</h1>
<div class="progress-container enemy-health">
  <progress class="progressplayer" id="playerhealth" value="80" max="100">
  </progress>
  <p class="progress-label">
    80%
  </p>
</div>
```

You'll have to play around with the label's `position`, depending on how you want to position it and style the progress bar.

Comment: Hello.Thanks for your great answer.I have 1 more question.What if i try to use this css style in 2 healthbars?i edited 1st post

Comment: Because we are using CSS classes, we can simply reuse the HTML that we coded the first time. See my updated answer, which stacks two of the `.progress-container`s. If you need to style each progress bar individually, you can simply add a unique class to each progress bar container like I did above with `.enemy-health` and `.player-health`.